# How to Use react js with yii2.0

Tags: reactjs, yii2

I have been doing **traditional design** using *HTMl, CSS* on my projects. This time i want to implement reactjs in the design. But i am unable to get clue about how to implement **reactjs** in my **YII2.0** project.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: I tried the process given in the link http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-react/  and installed in yii project but still could not figure how actually the codes works in yii2

Answer (score 5):

you can look on this project, this can be helpful and looks easy in implementation

[yii2-react](https://github.com/bTokman/yii2-react)

Comment: This is a link-only answer

Comment: I want to use React for entire pages in my Yii2 project, not just a widget. Can I use it for that?

Comment: Yes, you can put in widget config your main root component , and it would be render as default react app