# how to use react js and yii2 together

Tags: reactjs, yii2, fetch

I need to use react js as frontend and yii2 as backend.I've tried create-react-app for installing react. but it serves on port (cant serve on port:80). therefore I'm having trouble to fetch data from the backend.
the error I receive is (CORS error). but actually I need an absolute solution for fetching data from API.

Comment: allow `cors` in your backend? show us your relevant code?

Comment: @blueseal, not a good deal...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Use react js with yii2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529010/how-to-use-react-js-with-yii2-0)